# Android connection service scenarios

Tags: android, android-connectionservice

I was wondering if there is a list of case scenarios where Android's `ConnectionService` starts to engage or starts to be useful.

I can't find much about that on the internet, but I did find the following scenarios:

- denies new incoming call when emergency call is taking place
- puts current call on hold when new incoming call from a different app is answered
- handover calls between apps

I'm pretty sure there more.